# I want to compare the inserted date with current time in laravel 5 project

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I want to compare the inserted date with current time in laravel 5 project. Actually, I need to display an error message if the inserted date is already passed. Can anybody help me with that code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a validation rule to return that error for you.

```
$currentDate = Carbon::now();
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'dateField' => 'date|after:currentDate',
]);
if($validator->fails()){
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();    
}
```

then you can display the errors by using `$errors` variable in your view:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to tell your model that your 'insert' column is a date:

```
protected $dates = ['column_name'];
```

This will convert the `created_at` property to a [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com) instance, which has an `isPast()` method:

```
if ($model->column_name->isPast())
```

If you don't want to alter your model, you can create a Carbon instance manually.